# Why does int_vector.iterator fail to compile in Cython?

Tags: python, cython

I can use `vector[int].iterator`, but the seemingly equivalent `int_vector.iterator` causes an error:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

ctypedef vector[int] int_vector
cdef vector[int].iterator x
cdef int_vector.iterator y # ERROR: 'int_vector' is not a cimported module
```

Why is this happening, and is there a fix or a work-around?

Comment: File a bug report probably? https://github.com/cython/cython/issues

Comment: @DavidW I'm very new to Cython, so I just assumed that I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't think you are - it does look like it should work